# Can a BLDC motor meant for a multi-rotor be used for a fixed-wing aircraft?

Tags: brushless-motors, fixed-wing

I am designing a propulsion system for a fixed wing aircraft (RC plane). I have found a motor that meets all the requirements of my fixed wing aircraft. But the motor was for a multi rotor. Can we use the same motor for the fixed wing aircraft as well since it is providing the required amount of thrust?

Comment: How large are the two aircraft? There's nothing truly different about multirotor/fixed-wing BLDC motors except for their size. (and maybe some other minor specifics) A motor spec'd for a multirotor may be too small to drive the size of propeller needed for the fixed-wing aircraft.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, I have a few small planes using race quad motors that I had bought as spares. They work fine, although there are a few minor things to note.

The main thing to check is the speed rating of the motor, the 'Kv'. Race quads use quite small props, which have to spin fast. Planes tend to use larger props, spun more slowly, which is more efficient. If you're not too worried about efficiency, or are limited to a small prop, or are building a high-speed plane, these motors work fine.

The other issue is that race quad motors only have on option for mounting the prop. Fixed wing motors usually have a smooth shaft for a collet prop adapter, so you can adjust the prop position, which can be important if the motor is inside a cowl and you want a spinner to fit neatly. Prop adapters are available in a range of sizes for extra flexibility. Also the shaft can be reversed so it sticks out of the non-rotating side of the motor, for planes where the motor attaches to the very front of the plane (such as moulded fuselages).

If none of that is important to your model, you'll be fine.